Celery task processing issues on Windows
whenever a task is sent over to celery e.g.:

python 
>>> from tasks import sum_task
>>> result = sum_task.delay(4, 5)   # simple sum numbers function

celery crashes:
[2024-10-03 23:27:32,854: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function fast_trace_task at 0x0000020330335310> (args:('tasks.sum_task', '8fcfe22c-12e2-420c-af1b-2fe830acf23d', {'argsrepr': '(4, 33)', 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'id': '8fcfe22c-12e2-420c-af1b-2fe830acf23d', 'ignore_result': False, 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'lang': 'py', 'origin': 'gen80336@DominicRazer', 'parent_id': None, 'replaced_task_nesting': 0, 'retries': 0, 'root_id': '8fcfe22c-12e2-420c-af1b-2fe830acf23d', 'shadow': None, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}, 'task': 'tasks.sum_task', 'timelimit': [None, None], 'properties': {'content_type': 'application/json', 'content_encoding': 'utf-8', 'application_headers': {'argsrepr': '(4, 33)', 'eta': None, 'expires': None, 'group': None, 'group_index': None, 'id': '8fcfe22c-12e2-420c-af1b-2fe830acf23d', 'ignore_result': False, 'kwargsrepr': '{}', 'lang': 'py', 'origin': 'gen80336@DominicRazer', 'parent_id': None, 'replaced_task_nesting': 0, 'retries': 0, 'root_id': '8fcfe22c-12e2-420c-af1b-2fe830acf23d', 'shadow': None, 'stamped_headers': None, 'stamps': {}, 'task':... kwargs:{})
[2024-10-03 23:27:32,868: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: ValueError('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)')
billiard.einfo.RemoteTraceback:
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\.conda\envs\celery_demo\lib\site-packages\billiard\pool.py", line 362, in workloop
    result = (True, prepare_result(fun(args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\.conda\envs\celery_demo\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 664, in fast_trace_task
    tasks, accept, hostname = _loc
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
"""

Consulted:
claude 3.5 sonnet
gpt-4o

Celery does not support Windows. Some stuff may work though... Also, you could try MSYS2 - perhaps Python 3.x plus Celery work better there.

so (from a github thread and gpt4o)...
it looks like the latest versions of Celery (5.x and above) have some known compatibility issues with Windows due to differences in how multiprocessing and signal handling work across operating systems.
# the fix: use the solo flag for now (in mvp/development)

celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=info -P solo

The solo pool is a single-threaded option that can be used as a workaround on Windows. This pool is not suitable for production environments because it's limited to processing one task at a time, but it is helpful for development and debugging.

Just for note: I was added python-celery package to MSYS2. And eventlet pool can be used too.
